# laravel nova metrics accordig to filtered tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

i"m trying to make metrics of sales. I would like to filter the resaults with nova filters and o see for example total sales.

The metrics that Nova has are not useful for me.

i might filter:

-from date to date,

-filter only one customer,

-filter only retailers,

-filter only sales of one product model model,

-filter only one manufacturer,

It might be a combination of all those filters.

i there are endless options i might need. 
i dont want to create all those metrics.
I just want to filter and see the total sales.

does anyone has an idea ?